# Responsive height of a div using jquery .css

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello guys this is my first question here and it's about how to make my div with a responsive height usiing jquery.

This is the funcion I've used to try it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".panel").css("height: $('window').height();"); });
```

But when I save and I try to run my page I can't see anything because the height of the div is set to 0 I don't even know if this is the correrct way to do it...

Please help me with that and thanks for all.

Comment: You can use percentage ? `%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the jQuery way, you can do it like following:

```
 $('.panel').css('height', $(window).height()); 
 $(window).resize(function() {      
    $('.panel').css('height', $(window).height()); 
  });
```

**Check the following snippet example:**

```js
$(".panel").css("height", $(window).height());
$(window).resize(function() {
  $(".panel").css("height", $(window).height());
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  This is the panel
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
```

Also you can do it with one line of **CSS**, using `height:100vh;`
 Check the browser support for `vh`(viewport height),  **[Can I use vh](http://caniuse.com/#search=vh)**

```css
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.panel {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  This is the panel
</div>
```

Comment: @Pavlo B. Check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/q9fdx2sg/4/    if you want to set the height dynamically, yo need to add `window resize` event.
If you use body height, then, the height of the `.panel` will depend of the total height of the content inside the `body`